# (edited) Prove that if the union of a pair of (theories) $T_{1}\cup T_{2}$ is a theory, then $T_{1}\subseteq T_{2}$ or $T_{2}\subseteq T_{1} $

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I will shed some light on the context in which the term "pair" is used, as I warn whomever interested that we are dealing with substructural logics.

$Def.1$
An ordered pair $(x,y)$ of sets of formulas is said to be $\vdash$-pair $iff$ there are no formulas $A_{1}\wedge...\wedge A_{n}\in x$ and $B_{1}\vee...\vee B_{m}\in y$ where $A_{1}\wedge...\wedge A_{n}\vdash B_{1}\vee...\vee B_{m}$.

The theories are also closed under $\rightarrow$, $\wedge$, $\vee$. In the contextual lexicon, they are said to be **prime**. In particular:

$Def.2$
A theory $T$ in a certain deductive system is said to be **prime** iff $A\vee B \in T$ only if $A\in T$ **or** $B\in T.$

(Being closed under conjunction follows from the definition of a theory, and being closed under implication is called $\rightarrow$-detachment property)

I am trying to proceed as follows. If $A\in T_{1}$ and $B\in T_{2}$, then $A\wedge B\in T_{1}\cup T_{2}$. Since $X\vdash A$ and $Y\vdash B$, we need to prove that $X;Y\vdash A$ and $X;Y\vdash B$. This means that we have $X\vdash A$ and $Y\vdash A$.    Let's consider $T_{1}\nsubseteq T_{2}$, then if $A\notin T_{2}$, $Y\nvdash A$.

At this point my questions are:
1) Is this method valid? I think I am just proving that the two theories must be **at least** intersected, not one the subset of the other. (But if $X:= \land_{i}p$, where $p_{i}$ is a generic sentence in $T_{1}$, should do it)
2) Having proved the claim for $\wedge$, should I prove it also for $\rightarrow$ and $\wedge$, or one restriction is enough?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you sure the question is asking about prime theories and this special kind of pair? It seems to me the theorem is true if "theory" means closed under enrolment and "pair" just means two of them.

Comment: Yes. The only fallacy could be in my interpretation of "prime." I assumed it meant - for a theory closed under implication and conjunction - to be closed under disjunction. If that is the case, then the question asks about a pair of theories in a system that has $\rightarrow$, $\wedge$, $\vee$.

Comment: Closed under entailment, I mean

Comment: Do your theories have the property that if $A \wedge B \in T$ then $A \in T$ and $B \in T$?

Comment: According to the textbook (G.Restall's "An Introduction to Substructural Logic), the definition of a theory is:

T is a theory iff:

If $A\in T$ and $A \vdash B$, then $B\in T$


If the language contains conjunction, if $A,B \in T$, then $A \wedge B\in T$

Comment: OK, then here is your hint: forget for now about "prime" and the special kind of pair. Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are theories, with neither contained in the other. Take an $A$ only in $T_1$ and $B$ only in $T_2$. Use these to show $T_1 \cup T_2$ is not a theory, i.e., not closed under $\vdash$.

Comment: Your argument begins by taking $A$ in $T_1$ and $B$ in $T_2$, and assumes $T_1 \cup T_2$ is closed under $\wedge$ to get that $A \wedge B \in T_1 \cup T_2$.  This is fair enough, but I do not understand what comes after, e.g., why does $Y$ prove $A$ just because $X$ proves $A$ and $Y$ proves $B$? But here's an alternative next step: Since $A \wedge B$ is in $T_1 \cup T_2$, we can conclude that $A \wedge B$ is in either $T_1$ or $T_2$.

Comment: If A∈T1 and B∈T2, then A∧B∈T1∪T2, thus T1∪T2⊢A∧B. This means that, for the "∧ Introduction rule" (∧I), X;Y⊢A and X;Y⊢B. (The rule goes: if A⊢B and A⊢C, then A⊢B∧C. But then again, this means that X⊢A and Y⊢A, or else:  X⊢Y→A.